# What do the blue stars on areas mean?

Tags: pokemon-rumble-world

I noticed today when I went to fly my balloon, one area had a blue star on it. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stars increase the chance of finding rare and evolved Pokemon in that area.

Each area can have up to 3 stars on it, (1 blue, 2 green, 3 red).
Usually an area with **2 stars** has an evolved third-stage Pokemon as a boss (for example *Greninja* instead of Frogadier, *Talonflame* instead of Fletchinder, *Ampharos* instead of Flaaffy), **3 stars** grant you a *Legendary* Pokemon.
Random Pokemon are stronger, too. For example, in a 3-star level you can also find bosses in hordes.

As a side note: sometimes you can find a rainbow on the background of the area selection, which adds some random stars to the areas. This mechanic is called Fever.

More info on [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/rumbleworld/travel.shtml).

Comment: True, as another legendary example, on the RUBY balloon Groudon and Latias have a chance to appear on 3 red stars (This rarely happens without a fever, my best chance of this is during super fever)

Comment: @JDWhaler that's not so rare, I've found Latios and Groudon without a fever. (I've caught only the latter, unfortunately)